# horizontalscrollview gravity

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

How to make horizontalscrollview that move relatively object that is closer to the screen center? 
Like in the picture:

[image]

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's not clear what you are asking and the pictures don't provide clarification.

Comment: I wont make like here: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=678
but when only one page (picture) can see in the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find solution in the news-parser example. My code:

....

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        hs = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hs);
        hs.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (event.getAction() == 1)
                {
                    if (hs.getScrollX() > mWidth * 8 + mWidth / 2)
                    {
                        hs.smoothScrollBy(mWidth * 9 - hs.getScrollX(), 0);
                    }
                    else if (hs.getScrollX() > mWidth * (cN - 2)  + mWidth / 2)
                    {
                        hs.smoothScrollBy(mWidth * (cN - 1) - hs.getScrollX(), 0);
                    }
                    else if (hs.getScrollX() > mWidth / 2)
                    {
                        hs.smoothScrollBy(mWidth - hs.getScrollX(), 0);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hs.smoothScrollBy(-hs.getScrollX(), 0);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            //Log.v("e1.getX()", Float.toString(e1.getX()));
            //Log.v("e2.getX()", Float.toString(e2.getX()));
            //Log.v("velocityX", Float.toString(velocityX));
            if (velocityX > 0) {
                moveLeft();
            } else {
                moveRight();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void moveRight() {
        if (hs.getScrollX() > 0 && hs.getScrollX() < mWidth * cN)
        {
            hs.smoothScrollBy(mWidth * cN - hs.getScrollX(), 0);
            cN++;
        }
        //Log.v("cN", Integer.toString(cN));
    }

    private void moveLeft() {

        if (hs.getScrollX() > 0 && hs.getScrollX() < mWidth)
        {
            hs.smoothScrollBy( -hs.getScrollX(), 0);
            cN = 1;
        }
        else if (hs.getScrollX() > mWidth && hs.getScrollX() < mWidth * (cN - 1) )
        {
            hs.smoothScrollBy(mWidth * (cN - 2) - hs.getScrollX(), 0);
            cN--;
        }
        //Log.v("cN", Integer.toString(cN));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) will display the current item in the center of the window. See the [Gallery tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html) for details.

You can dynamically adjust the spacing of your items so that one item fills the screen by calling `setSpacing(int)`. (But is that what you want if, for instance, the activity is displaying in landscape mode on a tablet? That would be an empty-looking screen.)

Comment: But can I make so buttons gallery?

Comment: @user1136218 You can write a custom adapter so that the displayed views are Button views or anything else you like.